# Android EditText library similar to Path?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-chips

In my observation, the `EditText` pictured below is separated into 2 parts: one being a simple grid of which values are saved, and another being an actual `EditText`.

[image]

Has any of you know any `EditText` library that performs similarly like this? Or is there any alternative solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### That is called [Chips - Components - Google design guidelines](http://www.google.co.in/design/spec/components/chips.html)

#### See this libraries below :-

1. #### [TokenAutoComplete](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete)
2. #### [Material Chips](https://github.com/DoodleScheduling/android-material-chips)

> For example Add in your layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.tokenautocomplete.ContactsCompletionView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And all is done

#### Or You can create by your own using *SpannableStingBuilder* and *ImageSpan*